# Deploying using Beanstalk SVN Branches

Tags: svn, branch, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, beanstalk-svn

Beanstalk suggests having branches set up (in SVN) to act as listeners for deployment, (i.e. /branches/development/).

I know how to merge changes to a branch, if I'm currently working in that branch.

The question is, is it possible to push changes from the trunk or another branch to the deployment branch, while not actually working in the deployment branch.

Basically, I work either in the trunk of a feature branch and I want to be able to type in a quick command to push the latest set of changes from my working copy to the deployment branch. Can I do this? If so, can you provide an example?

Rich

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way with normal standalone svn to do a merge directly to the repository, you need to merge your changes to a working copy. Think of it like this, you needs some where to resolve all conflicts before finalizing the merge.

Answer (score 0):

To push the changes from the trunk (or another branch) to the deployment branch, **you need to merge** your modification to this deployment branch.

or, you can modify your deployment branch **to use external** and point to your feature branch. So when you update this branch, the external will do the job to point to the latest version.
This way, you don't have to modify the deployment branch.
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.externals.html

A third solution : you may be able to push directly your modification from the feature branch to the trunk with bazaar according that you push with bazaar to SVN repository (Bazaar has a svn plugin).
http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/beta/en/user-guide/svn_plugin.html

I hope this will help, at least to start.